# How to suppress Resharper wide-analysis warning of properties with Inject attribute?

Tags: c#, resharper, ninject, static-analysis

We use dependency injector Ninject in our C# project. The usual way of implementing it looks like this:

```
[Inject]
public UsersRepositoryInterface UsersRepository { private get; set; }
```

In addition to this, I enabled Resharper Wide Analysis for the solution, and it shows me to warnings in this line:

- Property 'VrtSystemsFlatRepository' can be made private
- Auto-property accessor is never used

[image]

My inner perfectionist suffers when he sees it, and I don't know how to avoid this warning.

I know about two ways, but I don't like both of them.

1. Add `UsedImplicitly` attribute in addition to `Inject`. The warning will be suppressed, but I need to add this Attribute to so many places.
2. Suppress the warning globally for the solution, for the project or file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add "MeansImplicitUse" annotation for "Ninject.InjectAttribute" in JetBrains's External annotations package:
https://github.com/JetBrains/ExternalAnnotations/issues/161

Comment: Do you mean this feature will be added to a new version of Annotations package?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Ninject to look for a custom attribute other than `[Inject]` by having the Kernel be passed a `NinjectSettings` with a different `InjectAttribute`. You should be able to inherit this custom attribute from `UsedImplicitly` to suppress the Resharper warning.

Comment: I see two issues here:
1) I need to update tons of code
2) If a new person joins our team it will be difficult for him/her to understand what is this 'different' InjectAttribute.